# CSS Positioning - Fixed Centre - Fixed Left & Fixed Right Elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure for a slide within a site created for an iPad

```
<div id="slide4">
    <div class="slide4A1"></div>
    <div class="slide4A2"></div>
    <div class="slide4A3"></div>
</div>
```

Each block contains background images which are controlled via media queries to allow them to fill the screen whether the Ipad is portrait or landscape.

I need to animate the blocks but want the positions to be as follows -

.slide4A1 - fixed left
  .slide4A2 - fixed centre
  .slide4A3 - fixed right

I have tried floating left and right for slides 1 and 3 and centering with auto margin- but the layout go's astray - any ideas?

js fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/chunk_pd/PAqSb/6/

Comment: could you please create Jsfiddle

Comment: yep sorry - here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/chunk_pd/PAqSb/

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dqz/

Comment: Bang on - cheers Kamo - if you add as an answer i'll give you a tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to clean your CSS - combining `position: absolute;` and `float` won't work. Use your wrapper `<div id="slide4">` and set its positioning as relative and `width: 100%`. Both animated divs have to have `position: absolute; top: 0px;` in order to reach top of the wrapper.

What is more - you have a typo in your JS:

`$('.slide4A1').animate({left:'0px;',}, 1600);` just remove ; after `0px` and voila.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you expected to see:

**CSS:**

```
#slide4 {position: relative; }
.slide4A1, .slide4A3{ position:absolute; top: 0; }
.slide4A1{background:#000;  width:120px; height:1024px; left:-120px;}
.slide4A2{background:#367ab2; width:531px; height:1024px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:relative!important; display: none;}
.slide4A3{background:#ff7e00; width:120px; height:1024px; right:-120px;}
```

**JS:**

```
function goDown3bPt2(){
                $('.slide4A1').animate({left:'0',}, 1600);
                $('.slide4A2').fadeIn('slow');
                $('.slide4A3').animate({right:'0',}, 2100);

        }
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAqSb/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Apply width :100%, margin:0 auto to slide4
width :33 % to slide4A1,slide4A2,slide4A3

Float Left to slide4A1 and float right to slide4A3 classes....!!

Comment: cheers Pratik, but the widths are different for each div unfortunately

Comment: but is that work for divs having same widths ? want brief about widths of div...!!

Comment: The code/css is in the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/chunk_pd/PAqSb/, widths of each div change according to the screen orientation - so not sure I could use percentages?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chunk_pd/PAqSb/6/  updated code with portrait/landscape dimensions

Comment: actually not getting whats going on with your fiddle.... but try to adjust css as.. because you are also animating that divs.. one suggestion : follow structure for divs and avoid setting left, maring-left,etc with pixels...